# How can I edit the response code that have already sent?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I made this code to send the response head quickly:

```js
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  fs.readFile(/*file path*/, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
    if (err) return res.writeHead(404).end('Not found');
    res.end(data);
  });
  res.writeHead(200);
});

server.listen(1337);
```

But if there's an error reading the file, the server sends response code twice (200=>404). Is there a way to edit the response code that was already sent?

Comment: Why don't you just move where writeHead(200) is, or use one of the higher level methods (e.g. res.send)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot modify a response code that's already sent because well, it's already sent.

You should handle each case separately:

```
fs.readFile(/*file path*/, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
  if (!err) {
    res.writeHead(200).end(data);
  } else if (err.code === 'ENOENT') {
    res.writeHead(404).end('Not Found');
  } else {
    res.writeHead(500).end('Internal Server Error');
  }
});
```

Also, as a general code style advice, consider using `async/await` to avoid ["callback hell"](https://www.velotio.com/engineering-blog/async-your-way-out-of-callback-hell).